# Tensorflow Object Detection Api UnknownError (see above for traceback): Failed to get convolution algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

When I tried to train model with

```
python3 model_main.py —logtostderr —train_dir=training/ —pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

I got following error

```
UnknownError (see above for traceback): Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try  looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
[[node FeatureExtractor/MobilenetV1/MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/Conv2D (defined at /home/paperspace/Desktop/models/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.py:266) ]]
[[node Loss/unstack (defined at /home/paperspace/Desktop/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/ssd_meta_arch.py:1073) ]]
```

Ubuntu 18.10

My Tensorflow version - 1.13.1

Cuda

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

Downgrade to 1.8.1 Tensorflow isn't solution
What is wrong? It could probably some dependency conflict

Comment: whats your Cudnn version ? I need these to answer your question

Comment: Could you help me with that? How can I check it?

Comment: are you using Linux? or windows? please mention your OS and GPU

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10, GPU - P4000. Cloud computing on Paperspace

Comment: can you type: conda env list . This will let you know if there are any virtual environments installed

Comment: 7.5.1.10-1+cuda10.0

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fugue it out. Since I have a clean version o Ubuntu (no pre install libraries), I did manage all dependencies manually. **Downgrade to 1.8.1** could be a solution in your case, but not in mine.

The environment that worked for me is

```
cudnn 7.5.1.10-1+cuda10.0
Tensorflow - 1.13.1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding these lines of code immediately after importing tensorflow

```
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import ConfigProto
from tensorflow.compat.v1 import InteractiveSession

config = ConfigProto()
config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
session = InteractiveSession(config=config)
```